# asp.net phonetic password generator

Tags: asp.net, passwords

i am generating random password.
but i want to get phonetic string of the password.
Any idea how can i get phonetic string?
example :

> deT3f9y => delta - echo -Tango -
>    number 3 - fox - number 9 - yankee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created class to generate phonetic string as below.

**USAGE:**

> string Psw = "deT3f9y"
>
> string Phone = Phonetic.GetPhoneticPassword(Psw);

```
enter code here
```

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// 
/// Summary description for Phonetic
/// 
public class Phonetic
{
    public Phonetic()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

```
public static string GetPhoneticPassword(string Passsord)
{
    string PhoneticString = string.Empty;
    char[] pswChar = Passsord.ToCharArray();
    foreach (char chr in pswChar)
    {
        if (PhoneticString == string.Empty)
        {
            PhoneticString = GetPhoneticSting(chr);
        }
        else
        {
            PhoneticString += " - " + GetPhoneticSting(chr);
        }
    }

    return PhoneticString;
}


public static string GetPhoneticSting(char Chr)
{
    string PhString= string.Empty;

    string Newchar = Chr.ToString();

    switch (Newchar.ToLower())
    {
        case "a":
            PhString = "alpfa";
            break;
        case "b":
            PhString = "bravo";
            break;
        case "c":
            PhString = "charlie";
            break;
        case "d":
            PhString = "delta";
            break;
        case "e":
            PhString = "echo";
            break;
        case "f":
            PhString = "foxtrot";
            break;
        case "g":
            PhString = "golf";
            break;
        case "h":
            PhString = "hotel";
            break;
        case "i":
            PhString = "item";
            break;
        case "j":
            PhString = "juliet";
            break;
        case "k":
            PhString = "kilo";
            break;
        case "l":
            PhString = "lima";
            break;
        case "m":
            PhString = "mike";
            break;
        case "n":
            PhString = "november";
            break;
        case "o":
            PhString = "oscar";
            break;
        case "p":
            PhString = "papa";
            break;
        case "q":
            PhString = "queen";
            break;
        case "r":
            PhString = "romeo";
            break;
        case "s":
            PhString = "sugar";
            break;
        case "t":
            PhString = "tango";
            break;
        case "u":
            PhString = "uniform";
            break;
        case "v":
            PhString = "victor";
            break;
        case "w":
            PhString = "whiskey";
            break;
        case "x":
            PhString = "x-ray";
            break;
        case "y":
            PhString = "yankee";
            break;
        case "z":
            PhString = "zulu";
            break;
        case "1":
            PhString = "One";
            break;
        case "2":
            PhString = "Two";
            break;
        case "3":
            PhString = "Three";
            break;
        case "4":
            PhString = "Four";
            break;
        case "5":
            PhString = "Five";
            break;
        case "6":
            PhString = "Six";
            break;
        case "7":
            PhString = "Seven";
            break;
        case "8":
            PhString = "Eight";
            break;
        case "9":
            PhString = "Nine";
            break;
        case "0":
            PhString = "Zero";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if(CheckUpper(Chr.ToString()))
    {
        PhString = PhString.ToUpper();
    }

    return PhString;

}

public static bool CheckUpper(string strCheck)
{
    if(string.Compare(strCheck,strCheck.ToUpper())==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have a lookup table that translates the characters into words ('a' -> "alpha") and then iterate over the characters in the generated password, looking up the word.